# Using mencoder to record a video

Tags: camera, mplayer, mencoder

I'm trying to use `mencoder` to record a video. The following command was taken from an [online tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Webcam_setup#MPlayer):

```
mencoder tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:width=640:height=480:device=/dev/video0:forceaudio:adevice=/dev/dsp -ovc lavc -oac mp3lame -lameopts cbr:br=64:mode=3 -o filename.avi
```

The output is as follows:

```
MEncoder SVN-r37379 (C) 2000-2015 MPlayer Team
210 audio & 441 video codecs
success: format: 9  data: 0x0 - 0x0
TV file format detected.
Selected driver: v4l2
 name: Video 4 Linux 2 input
 author: Martin Olschewski <olschewski@zpr.uni-koeln.de>
 comment: first try, more to come ;-)
v4l2: your device driver does not support VIDIOC_G_STD ioctl, VIDIOC_G_PARM was used instead.
Selected device: UVC Camera (046d:0825)
 Capabilities:  video capture  streaming
 supported norms:
 inputs: 0 = Camera 1;
 Current input: 0
 Current format: YUYV
tv.c: norm_from_string(pal): Bogus norm parameter, setting default.
v4l2: ioctl enum norm failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Error: Cannot set norm!
Selected input hasn't got a tuner!
Unable to open '/dev/dsp': No such file or directory
Unable to open '/dev/dsp': No such file or directory
Unable to open '/dev/dsp': No such file or directory
v4l2: ioctl set mute failed: Invalid argument
v4l2: 0 frames successfully processed, 0 frames dropped.
============ Sorry, this file format is not recognized/supported =============
=== If this file is an AVI, ASF or MPEG stream, please contact the author! ===
Cannot open demuxer.

Exiting...
user@ArchBox:~/Dropbox$ mencoder tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:width=640:height=480:device=/dev/video0:forceaudio:ade[15838:17998:0117/045341:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_nss.cc(922)] CERT_PKIXVerifyCert for api.tldr.io failed err=-8181
```

How do I address these errors?

Answer (score 0):

In the command string given, it looks like the audio device has not been correctly specified.

Saith mencoder:

```
Unable to open '/dev/dsp': No such file or directory
```

In the exiting command line it says:

```
:forceaudio:adevice=/dev/dsp
```

Try

```
:forceaudio:alsa:adevice=hw.1:buffersize=64
```

This gets audio from device `hw.1` in the ALSA sub system. Note that it's `hw.1` here, **not** `hw:1` which might be more usual in the ALSA world.

No guarantees, but it works for me in Kubuntu 18.04 I use it with `mplayer` and `mencoder` to display & encode VCR VHS video via an Honestech usb video interface box.